# How to authorize Google Identity Platform REST API requests?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, authorization, google-identity

My team is using GIP for authentication and authorization of users in our SaaS product.
We need to bulk migrate users and keep their custom claims up to date, all of this is easy with the admin SDKs that Google provides.

However our backend is written in Ruby, for which there is no SDK support. This means that we have to use the REST API directly and I cannot find any documentation on how to authorize these REST requests using the *service account* credentials, e.g.

```json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project_id",
  "private_key_id": "private_key_id",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n foo\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "foo@bar.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "client_id",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service-account-name%40bar.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

How do you use service account credentials to Authorize a GIP REST API request? Do I need to somehow generate a token from this JSON, and sign it with the private key?

Comment: I wrote an article that shows you how to create the OAuth access token and make a REST API call in Python: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: @JohnHanley I would mark your comment as the answer if I could. I was about 70-80% of the way there and your article got me over the finish line. Many thanks.